# Gods and Super Humans

Tags: gods, goddess

I read somewhere, long back, that before Humans existed, there were Super-Humans on this earth. This was after the Dinosaurs got extinct and this was a way of Nature to re-start life on earth after the mass extinction of all kinds of life.
Is it true, that the Super-humans were none other than our Gods, who also scripted there daily routine through our religious scriptures. And once the normal life was established, they left the earth gradually.

Comment: Malay, Please check the code of conduct of Hinduism Stack exchange before shooting questions. Your question is half way through.

Comment: Sure Mr Raghavan. Though I always believe Science has been the basis of Sanatan Dharma, and anything related to history has to be connected to Sanatan Dharma.

Answer (score 2):

> And once the normal life was established, they left the earth
> gradually.

In Vedas and other scriptures it is mentioned that once upon a time gods and humans used to live together on earth. But, then the gods left and settled in the heavens. So, this particular statement of yours is true as per scriptures:

> **In ancient times gods and men used to live together in  this world.
> Then the gods went to heaven by performing rites, while men were left
> behind**.* Those among them who perform rites in the same manner get
> to dwell in that world together with the gods and Brahman.
>
> *Dharmasutras of Apasthambha 2.16.1*

> I read somewhere, long back, that before Humans existed, there were
> Super-Humans on this earth.

IMO, there is an indirect mention of "super humans", who were such powerful that they were even able to defy the Law of Karma, which even deities can't escape from.

> 7 **Transgression of the Law and violence are seen among people of
> ancient times. 8 They incurred no sin on account of their
> extraordinary power**. 9 A man of later times who, observing what they
> did, does the same, perishes
>
> *Dharmasutras of Apasthambha 2.14.7-9*

What it says is that those ancient humans were so powerful that they committed sins but were not affected by them, due to their "extraordinary power".

So, this is an indirect reference to "super humans" IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps.

Comment: No problem .. keep participating on the site :) @MalayDwivedi